# Photoshop drawing shape acts like option key is pressed

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Photoshop CC 2015, and for some reason now whenever I draw a shape, it acts like the option key is pressed. And it works normally when I press the option key.

Somehow the option key is toggled, if you will. What could be the reason?

**Edit:** This is only when I'm drawing a rectangle apparently, it works fine with other shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You Checked the **"From center"** Button in the Settings of Rectangle tool.

Unchecked that **"From center"** button and your rectangle tool Will work Fine.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome welcome @hattenn